# Environment variable error while trying to create a solver in OpenFOAM 9

Tags: c++, linux, bash, environment-variables, openfoam

I'm trying to create a solver in my `/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/applications/solvers/electromagnetics` directory using `sudo foamNewSource App newSolver`. But, I keep getting the following error:

```
foamNewSource: Creating new interface file newSolver.C
wmakeFilesAndOptions error: environment variable $WM_OPTIONS not set
```

And then, although I can see a `newSolver.C` file, I cannot see a `Make` directory and neither the rest of the files.

I'm running EndeavourOS Linux x86_64 with kernel 5.15.6-arch2-1 and shell bash 5.1.12. I installed the `openfoam-org` package from the `AUR`, and in order to set it up, I have the following in my `.bashrc` config file:

```
source /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/etc/bashrc
```

At first, when I did `env | grep WM` I couldn't find `WM_OPTIONS` in my system. So, after googling a little bit, I added this to my .bashrc file:

```
source /opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/etc/bashrc
export WM_OPTIONS=linux64GccDPOpt
```

And now, doing `env | grep WM` I get:

```
WM_COMPILER=Gcc
WM_PRECISION_OPTION=DP
WM_PROJECT_USER_DIR=/home/username/OpenFOAM/username-9
WM_MPLIB=SYSTEMOPENMPI
WM_OPTIONS=linux64GccDPOpt
WM_ARCH=linux64
WM_LABEL_SIZE=32
WM_PROJECT=OpenFOAM
WM_THIRD_PARTY_DIR=/opt/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-9
WM_LABEL_OPTION=Int32
WM_CC=gcc
WM_CFLAGS=-m64 -fPIC
WM_LINK_LANGUAGE=c++
WM_OSTYPE=POSIX
WM_PROJECT_VERSION=9
WM_DIR=/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9/wmake
WM_ARCH_OPTION=64
WM_CXXFLAGS=-m64 -fPIC -std=c++0x
WM_PROJECT_INST_DIR=/opt/OpenFOAM
WM_LDFLAGS=-m64
WM_CXX=g++
WM_COMPILE_OPTION=Opt
WM_PROJECT_DIR=/opt/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-9
WM_COMPILER_TYPE=system
WM_COMPILER_LIB_ARCH=64
```

Now I can see the `WM_OPTIONS` environment variable (just above `WM_ARCH=linux64` and below `WM_MPLIB=SYSTEMOPENMPI`), but I still get the same `wmakeFilesAndOptions` error.

I don't know what configuration I'm messing up, so I'd appreciate some help!

Thanks!

Comment: It is a bad idea to use sudo. create your solver in your home directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using sudo in this case is not a good idea, instead run the scripts on your home directory:

```
mkdir -p $FOAM_RUN
cd $FOAM_RUN
foamNewSource App newSolver
```

For `WM_OPTIONS` environment variable, don't set it manually, instead use:

```
export WM_OPTIONS=$WM_ARCH$WM_COMPILER$WM_PRECISION_OPTION$WM_LABEL_OPTION$WM_COMPILE_OPTION
```